# Dual boot menu not showing after installation of Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, software-installation

Before installing `Ubuntu 12.04`, `Windows XP` with three drives were there. I've installed `Ubuntu 12.04` 64 bit in of the three drives which I've mentioned above, installation went fine but after installation `Dual boot` screen is not showing, windows is automatically loading.

I've tried answers which are found here and other `Ubuntu forums` but non of them is worked for me. From forums what I came to know is,`Grub` missing. To install or to repair it, I'm unable to login to Ubuntu, then how can `upgrade grub` in `ubuntu`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repair Grub by booting an Ubuntu Live-CD and using the program "Boot-Repair".

If you have an Internet connection you can just insert your Ubuntu CD (the one you used for installing ubuntu 12.04) and select "Try Ubuntu". It will then boot a live environment of Ubuntu from the CD.
Here you can install Boot-Repair via the Terminal. Type:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

After that launch Boot-Repair and select "Recommended Repair". 
That should do the trick and reconfigure/-install Grub.

Better and more detailed instructions can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Good luck! :)

Comment: I've already found that link, whenever I give `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`, it showing the error as `add-apt-repository: command not found`

Comment: The trouble was with my `Firewall`, issue is solved now. But if I won't select any operating system for few seconds then `Ubuntu` is loading automatically, can I increase waiting time to select OS ?

Answer (score 1):

If you did not install inside windows xp, now boot to your Ubuntu Live CD or your bootable USB Stick with Ubuntu inside.
Open Terminal.

Enter:

```
sudo blkid
```

and press enter.

Then you will see a detail list of all your drives and devices. Your first drive looks like this:

```
...
/dev/sda1: UUID="xxxxxxx..." TYPE="ext4"
...
```

Enter:

```
sudo mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

to mount your first drive.

Finally:

```
sudo grub-install --boot-directory=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Note that your final command here does not end with /dev/sda1, it ends with /dev/sda, because grub-install must install grub on MBR (the Boot Record of whole your harddisk), not Boot Record of any drive (likes C:, D:, E: on windows).

Now exit terminal and reboot your computer.

Answer (score -2):

I do had the same problem.
It was all about loosing your boot up order.

Try restoring it...

You may use [boot-repair](http://jaist.dl.sourceforge.net/project/boot-repair-cd/boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso).