# After installed ubuntu on my windows 8.1, boot menu not shown, i directly deleted the ubuntu hard disk partition

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I'm having HP r014tx, windows 8.1 OS, i dual booted ubuntu and its successfully installed after i restarted boot menu option not showing and directly enters into windows 8.1, i tried installing easy BCD and grub2 and not resolved, so i directly deleted the ubuntu hard disk partition and again allocated into windows partition, but now my problem is if i long press shift while restart  and press F9 bios option is still showing ubuntu(H19XXX) option like that, so what can i do now? please help me quickly,i'm really fed up because i'm suspecting it may cause my windows os as its my new laptop.

I want to ubuntu as well again i can re-install ubuntu?
Kindly help quickly.

Regards,
Santhosh.
+91-9860895438

Comment: Don't worry,windows is still there.Re-install ubuntu with live cd and you will get a partition option there.

Comment: I think your grub resolution does not fit with your display.

Comment: but while i restarted boot menu option is not showing-for that can you please guide me step by step process plz.

Comment: You have deleted the ubuntu partition,so you have to re-install it first,then allocate the deleted part for ubuntu

Comment: but while i restarted boot menu option is not showing-for that can you please guide me step by step process plz...

Comment: A black screen is staying at first before the booting of windows.Isn't it?

Comment: no black screen staying, its only shows my initial hp startup window and enters into my windows login page...

Comment: see this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/256879/dual-boot-menu-not-showing-after-installation-of-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: ok,so from that above link i understand, i have to re-install ubuntu and then again repair grub by booting a cd,but for doing this, whats a proper way to install, what are all the things had to done priorly, like disable secure boot and turn off check mark removed only this 2. or anythingelse plz confirm.

2nd- when i open a termina and  type this comment sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
it asking me for a password which password i can give,login password n not working, and this password typing section fully freezed.i cannnot able to type anything here.

Comment: You have to give the administrator password there.And while installing select 'Try ubuntu' not the 'Install Ubuntu'.After solving the problem install it.

Comment: administrator password is same as my windows login password and ubuntu login password, that password section i can't able to type anything its freezed up

Comment: It's ok.This is a property of linux,it doesn't show the password typing.Just type it and press enter.

Comment: ok i'll check and again ask you if anything happens, and is it possible to help me thorugh mobile phone, i'll call you if u give ur no.its bit urgent...that's why?

Comment: wow great...very thanks boss...thank you so much...

Comment: An error occurred during the repair.

Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste2.org/0jWfNysa

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com

You can now reboot your computer.
Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda (1000GB) disk! Please disable SecureBoot in the BIOS.

Comment: The boot files of [The OS now in use - Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS] are far from the start of the disk. Your BIOS may not detect them. You may want to retry after creating a /boot partition (EXT4, >200MB, start of the disk). This can be performed via tools such as gParted. Then select this partition via the [Separate /boot partition:] option of [Boot Repair]. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your laptop HP r014tx,boot options come in different ways-While booting press `Esc` then press `F9` to get the boot or OS options.Hope it works!!

Comment: yes its working fine...resolved...

Comment: Thanks Saptarshi Nag...For your ultimate continuous support...without hesitating to answer my all the questions...really appreciated...